# Jquery UI tabs at bottom, i can't align the arrow for active tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, tabs

im trying to wreck my brains over this all of last 2 days

this is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wd7a6/

I have added the arrow in active tabs but I'm unable to position it

please let me know what I am doing wrong

```
.ui-state-active a::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    top:-20; 
    display:block;
}
```

I'm sorry for not being able o explain properly see the screenshot and you will understand[image]

Comment: where do you want it to be placed ?

Comment: i have updated my question with a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/wd7a6/4/)

```
.ui-state-active a::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    top: -5px;//added this
    left: 20px;//added this
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar I tried the same and it worked. you can see on www.spheretekk.com/bc. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the arrow left-aligned with the text:

```
.ui-state-active a:before {
    content: "";
    position: relative; /*Use relative to ensure that the generated content is not removed from normal document flow, otherwise it will overlap the other content */
    height: 0px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    top: 0px;
    left: -10px; /* specify a negative left to control offset on the left */
    display: inline-block; /*Use inline-block to ensure that the generated content stays inline with the other content */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wd7a6/1/

If you want it right-aligned with the text, use `:after` and specify a positive left for the offset from the tab text.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wd7a6/2/